# Why a method works differently with a list when stored in the variable and used and in other case not stored, but used directly?

Tags: python, pandas

This works..

```
indices = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
sample_reviews = reviews.loc[indices]
```

But... this does not works the same way, instead shows an error

```
sample_reviews = reviews.loc[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You need to pass a list into loc which itself is accessed with square brackets. This should work: `sample_reviews = reviews.loc[[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]]`

Comment: Does `loc.__getitem__` really required a list instead of a tuple? Because that's the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case your are passing a `list` called `indicies` to the function, which is correct. In the second, you are passing 5 ints, which is incorrect. You need to change the second to:

```
sample_reviews = reviews.loc[[1, 2, 3, 5, 8]]
```